# is there any Eclipse plug-in for WYSIWYG html editing/creating?

Tags: html, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

it's a very easy question maybe, but i can't find any "working" plug in for WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) HTML editing ,you know like dream weaver

i'm developing a web site which is a mix of php and python, coding is comfortable but designing is very hard with out such a plug in

thnx :)

Comment: I am using Aptana Studio 1.5 which is not a WYSIWYG like dreamweaver but it has a Firefox and IE preview tab. Using a WYSIWYG editor to design a websign is suboptimal. And why should someone using eclipse use a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: i'm using it because i'm conformable with it, and now i need WYSIWYG so if i get one i will have an IDE fits perfectly to my needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Havn't tried it, but MyEclipse has an visual HTML designer. Maybe it's sufficient for your needs?

http://www.myeclipseide.com/

http://www.myeclipseide.com/images/tutorials/demos/html_designer_snap/html_designer_snap.htm

Comment: the thing is i don't want the whole MYEclipse i just want the HTML editor from it, is that possible ?
thanks for you're reply :)

Comment: As MyEclipse is commercial I don't think you can get only the HTML editor.