# html/css/jquery/javascript code completion in php file phpEclipse

Tags: php, html, css, code-completion, phpeclipse

This is my first post at this site. I searched alot but couldn't find what i was looking for so i decided to post the question.

Im a php developer. I was using dreamweaver because i like many features of dreamweaver like code/design view, html/css/jquery/javascript code completion within PHP file. The reason why i am switching from dreamweaver that it doest not provide debugging for php.

I installed phpeclipse and found it very promising but its missing many features i really liked in dreamweaver. I managed to install web page editor for design view but code completion for html css etc in php file is not working.

Is it possible to add all these features in phpeclipse? or 
Is it possible to find all these feature in some other php IDE other than phpeclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you consider using Netbeans IDE? Way much better than any others. :) I use it... :D

Comment: i tried Netbeans by sun but couldn't find code completion for html css etc in php file. am i missing something? or are these any plugins for these features?

Comment: do you need to install some plugin to make code completion work or does it work in the default download package ? and can you please tell me which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Netbeans IDE 7.2, the latest one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed. There are two ways for the above. Netbeans 7.2 comes with a great support for PHP and also has some good plugins. The other way is that you can install apatana studio plugin in eclipse which provides autocompletion in css,html and JavaScript. Both the IDE's are promising. Try to install Apatana Studio on phpeclipse since it comes as a plugin. This would solve your problem. I would strongly suopport Apatana Studio with your existing setup for PHP in eclipse. Here is the link http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download The above mentioned link is the download page.

Comment: im installing aptana plugin its taking some time, i'll post comment after installation. Thanks for your response.

Comment: installation is quite slow, still in progress. in the meantime can you suggest me plugin for design view other than web page editor. web page editor works fine for .html .css files but if i view design view of .php "html integrated php file" then it doesn't work and shows some error.

Comment: I actually find out these links which can be interesting  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973238/is-there-any-eclipse-plug-in-for-wysiwyg-html-editing-creating  ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868/what-is-the-best-html-editor-for-eclipse , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437583/eclipse-plugin-for-html-wysiwyg-editor   Have a look. I havent tried it out but may be useful.

Comment: installation is still under progress i'll let you know when it gets completed. and for the links you provided they all mentioned Web Page Editor for html design view. I already installed it but it only works for .html files not for .php files. Im not sure why its behaving like this.

Comment: aptana plugin is pretty good. html and css code completion is awesome but javascript code completion is not that good and it doesn't support jquery. any suggestions for javascript and jquery auto compeltion ?

Comment: @AaqibIqbal   It does have Autocompletion using  some tweak. Just check the anwser to the question I Have linked to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enable-jquery-support-in-aptana-studio-3 . Hope after using this you wont have much problem and I would have the points ;)

Comment: you answers really helped me. im going to stick to phpeclipse for a while to explore it completely. i've accepted your anwers but couldn't vote you as im new a user and for vote up i must have 15 reputations and currently i haven't got any. Sorry for that.

Comment: @AaqibIqbal Thats absolutely fine :) Hope u enjoy apatana and phpeclipse